# Best practice Cypress - cy.visit() or clicking on links

Tags: automation, cypress

I am thinking which is best practice to follow in cypress.

Scenario: Either I can click on link which loads a new page or use cy.visit() to go directly to that page. May I know which is recommended/ best practice? cy.visit() drastically decreases the time for running the tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to test.

If you'd like to test some page and you don't care how to get to it, you should use cy.visit('/my-page-to-test'). This way your test will be shorter and run faster.

On the other hand, if you want to test navigation and that links are working properly, you need cy.contains('my link').click() or cy.get('a[href=something]').click(). And in case the link is absent or hidden or anything else prevents using it, your test will crash. This is a good way to test that users can navigate your website.